# Getting Jwt Token for current user logged in with AzureAd In c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-ad-msal

I used AzureAd for authentication. the login is working and has no problem.
Now I'm trying to get AzurAd Token for the user who is logged in and send it to another API.
I tried to use AcquireTokenAsync but it doesn't return the groups and full token, or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these docs I got access token successfully here.

I think you also saw [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=aspnetcore) for enable login. And this is for [calling api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

my appsetting.json

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "domain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "ClientId": "2c0exxxxxxxdf157",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "O67Q3xxxxxxxxZ-J"
  },
  "GraphBeta": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  }
```

My startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd")
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
               .AddDownstreamWebApi("MyApi", Configuration.GetSection("GraphBeta")).AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
        }
```

My controller

```
using aspnetcore_azuread.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace aspnetcore_azuread.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "user.read" })]
        public async Task<string> testAsync() {
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
            return accessToken;
        }


        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```